# How in multimap run for range from to?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, range, multimap

I need to go from the beginning +3 and from the end -3
that is, if the total size is 10, then I have to iterate from 3 to 7
who it doesnt work?

```
std::multimap<int,int> _multimap;
for(auto it = _multimap.begin() + 3; it != _multimap.end() - 3; it++) {
    std::cout << it->first;
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: expand on *doesn't work*. If you're tripping over a compiler error, add it to the question. In general, produce a [mre] complete with inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs and see if simply having all that in front of you in one place is enough to see the problem yourself. If it doesn't add it all to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the class template `std::multimap` does not have random access iterators. It has bidirectional iterators.

So you may not write

```
_multimap.begin() + 3

or

_multimap.end() - 3
```

Instead you could write the for loop the following way using standard function `std::next` and `std::prev`

```
#include <iterator>

//...

for( auto first = std::next( _multimap.begin(), 3 ),
     last = std::prev( _multimap.end(), 3 ); 
     first != last;
     ++first ) {
    /// TODO: something happen
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::multimap<int, char> m =
    {
        { 65, 'A' }, { 66, 'B' }, { 67, 'C' }, { 68, 'D' }, { 69, 'E' },
        { 70, 'F' }, { 71, 'G' }, { 72, 'H' }, { 73, 'I' }, { 74, 'J' },
    };

    for ( auto first = std::next( std::begin( m ), 3 ), last = std::prev( std::end( m ), 3 );
          first != last;
          ++first )
    {
        std::cout << first->first << ": " << first->second << '\n';
    }        
}
```

The program output is

```
68: D
69: E
70: F
71: G
```

If you want to have the range of elements [3, 7 ] then instead of

```
last = std::prev( std::end( m ), 3 )
```

you need to write

```
last = std::prev( std::end( m ), 2 )
```

Do not forget to include the header `<iterator>`.

Comment: and even if you use vector you will get elements 3 thru 6 not 3 thru 7

Comment: @pm100 It is unimportant what range he is going to use. I have taken its expression where it is used -3.:)